# Javascript clearTimeout help pls

Tags: javascript

hi everyone this is my code:

```
var stopKick;
let timerID = setInterval(function() {
  // function kicked() { setTimeout( room.kickPlayer(player.id , " Lütfen hesabını onayla -> [ public.haxlife.com ] " , false) , 30000 ); clearInterval(timerID); }
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/BOT/publicBOT/kesinOnay.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      nickname: nick
    },
    success: function(data) { // Kicklenme sorununda kaldın!
      console.log(data);
      if (data == 'dogrulanmamis') {
        stopKick = setTimeout(function() {
          console.log("denem")
        }, 30000)
      } else {
        clearTimeout(stopKick);
        room.sendChat("Profilin Eşleşti İyi Oyunlar , " + player.name, player.id);
        clearInterval(timerID);
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("eslesmede hataa");
    }
  });
}, 3000);
```

but this clearTimeout not working

Comment: You need to debug and find out why. console.log() is your friend

Comment: Your `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` will never both be called, since they're in different blocks of an `if/else` - Can you describe the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: If `clearTimeout()` isn't being called, then `data == 'dogrulanmamis'` must always be true.

Comment: You need to provide more information such as what you're trying to achieve. Without any context I look at that code and wonder what you're expecting from it.

Comment: click the button on a php page confirm. in PHP will query the database and if the user queries the database correctly, 'basardindostum' will be printed and setTimeout not work, but if it is not true, it will print 'not verified' 30 seconds after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create a new timer every time the AJAX call occurs and `data == 'dogrulanmamis'` is true. When the condition is false, you only cancel the last one.

Either you should only start the timer once, or cancel the old one before starting a new one. Here's how to do it the first way.

```
var stopKick;
let timerID = setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/BOT/publicBOT/kesinOnay.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      nickname: nick
    },
    success: function(data) { // Kicklenme sorununda kaldın!
      console.log(data);
      if (data == 'dogrulanmamis') {
        if (!stopKick) {
          stopKick = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("denem")
          }, 30000);
        }
      } else {
        clearTimeout(stopKick);
        room.sendChat("Profilin Eşleşti İyi Oyunlar , " + player.name, player.id);
        clearInterval(timerID);
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("eslesmede hataa");
    }
  });
}, 3000);
```

Comment: This called a mutex. Google it. That will help you recognise and avoid this class of problems in the future.

Comment: Great answer, btw @Barmar!

Comment: @JoshWulf It's not really a mutex. Mutexes are used to coordinate access to a common resource by concurrent processes/threads.

Comment: Yes, in the sense " a mutex is a binary flag used to protect a shared resource by ensuring mutual exclusion inside critical sections of code. " This protects the timer from being activated by multiple invocations of `success`.

Comment: It's for protecting against multiple concurrent accesses, you're generalizing too far.